# Failed to load the LayoutLib: com/android/layoutlib/bridge/Bridge : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0

Tags: android

```
org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.RenderingException: Failed to load the LayoutLib: com/android/layoutlib/bridge/Bridge : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.LayoutLibraryLoader.load(LayoutLibraryLoader.java:90) 
at org.jetbrains.android.sdk.AndroidTargetData.getLayoutLibrary(AndroidTargetData.java:180) 
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createTask(RenderService.java:164)    at com.intellij.android.designer.designSurface.AndroidDesignerEditorPanel$7.run(AndroidDesignerEditorPanel.java:514)    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:337)  at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:327)  at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$3.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:271) 
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:286) 
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:244) 
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:234) 
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238) 
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:352) 
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:439) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:303) 
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:138) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.runTask(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:895) 
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:918) 
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:695)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Usually you get error: **Unsupported major.minor version 52.0**

If you have installed Android N, change Android rendering version with older one and the problem will disappear.

[image]